# What will be the unit of mass in $E=mc^2$ when energy units change?

Tags: energy, unit-conversion

I know that conventionally the unit of $E$ in $E=mc^2$ is taken as joules when mass is in $\mathrm{kg}$. But I am doing some calculations of my own with different units of energy ($\mathrm{keV}$,$\mathrm{MeV}$ etc.). So my question is whether we have to convert $\mathrm{keV}$ or $\mathrm{MeV}$ to joules in order to calculate mass or we can keep the values of $\mathrm{KeV}$, $\mathrm{MeV}$ units and then find mass (I think this method is easier)? If we are keeping $\mathrm{keV}$ and $\mathrm{MeV}$ then what will be the unit of mass, will it still be $\mathrm{kg}$? I am a chemist so please forgive if I asked an irrational question.

Advanced thanks for your help

Comment: The easy conversion is that 1GeV is 1 proton, or 1 gram divided by 1 mole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit can be anything as long as you carry out the proper conversion. If you're using $KeV$ and $MeV$, there isn't any complete unit system that specifies the units of speed (which we need to convert to mass).

Usually, particle physicists use $MeV$ as a *mass* unit as well as energy (thereby setting $c=1$ in this unit system). Later on stuff can be converted to SI by normal $eV$-to-Joules conversion, followed by division by $c^2$ in SI if we want mass. This unit system may be helpful for you calculations.

One can't generally ask "If so-and-so is in abc unit, what is the unit of xyz?", unless more examples are provided. For example, you *can* ask the above question as "If energy is in MeV, and speed is in ly/s (made-up useless unit), then what's the unit of mass?". Here, the answer would be $\frac{MeV\times s^2}{ly^2}$.

Comment: You'll also occasionally see the mass unit written as $\frac{\rm MeV}{c^{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general the units of energy will be $\frac{\text{[Mass]}\text{[distance]}^2}{\text{[time]}^2}$, where you substitute in the units for mass, distance and time that you have chosen.

It is the relationship between them that matters, not what you call them.